# Ripple animation effect over MapView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-mapview

Is there a way to create a ripple effect over the MapView?

My layout is presented in the end of the post.
I know about `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` and it works great on different kinds of Views, but not with the MapView.

What I want is the indivisible ripple effect over `header_container` and `map_view`.

To reach this I have tried putting them inside RelativeLayout and creating View with `selectableItemBackground` above them, but I don't like this solution because I could only make it work by specifying the exact height of that overlapping view and I want it to match the height of header and map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cv_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_horizontal_padding">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_text_small_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_text_big_margin"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="@dimen/card_title_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_text_small_margin"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textSize="@dimen/card_subtitle_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_media_height"
            map:liteMode="true"
            map:mapType="none" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/card_action_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_action_padding">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/b_drive"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_action_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_action_padding"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_action_padding"
                android:text="@string/card_action_drive"
                android:textColor="@color/color_primary" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/b_walk"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_action_padding"
                android:text="@string/card_action_walk"
                android:textColor="@color/color_primary" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following class is a recipe to put any overlay on top of any view.
All you have to do is replace `extends View` to `extends Anything` and then call `setOverlay(...);` with the overlay (in you specific question a Ripple).

so in your case it will be:

```
extends MapView
```

and then

```
mapView.setOverlay(mapView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple));
```

and here is the "recipe" class

```
public class PressedStateView extends View {
   public PressedStateView(Context context) {
      super(context);
   }

   public PressedStateView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
   }

   public PressedStateView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
   }

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
   public PressedStateView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
   }

   private Drawable overlay;

   public void setOverlay(Drawable overlay) {
      if (this.overlay != null) {
         this.overlay.setCallback(null);
      }
      this.overlay = overlay;
      this.overlay.setCallback(this);
      this.overlay.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      invalidate();
   }

   @Override protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
      super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
      this.overlay.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
   }

   @Override protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
      return super.verifyDrawable(who) || who == overlay;
   }

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) @Override
   public void drawableHotspotChanged(float x, float y) {
      super.drawableHotspotChanged(x, y);
      if (overlay != null) {
         overlay.setHotspot(x, y);
      }
   }

   @Override protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
      if (overlay != null) {
         overlay.draw(canvas);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'm testing it right now, could you please show your `R.drawable.ripple`?

Comment: just a normal XML drawable: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html You have to see how you want the color and if there's a selector or not. That's your design.